# How to change the value of multiple observations in R

Tags: r, replace

I'm new to R. In the dataset, the value for "zero not good mental health days" is 88. I would like to change that number to 0 so I can get the average number of not good mental health days for the state of Pennsylvania.

```
avgMHNotGoodPenn <- brfss2 %>%
  select(menthlth, state)%>%
  filter(state == '42') %>%
  mutate(replace(value=88, 0),
         avgMHNotGood= mean(menthlth))%>%
  select(menthlth, avgMHNotGood)%>%
  head(1)
```

This code returns an average of 62.4 but hasn't replaced the 88s with 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ifelse` to assign new values to your data frame `brffs`:

```
brfss2 <- data.frame(menthlth = c(0, 1, 40, 88))
brfss2
#>   menthlth
#> 1        0
#> 2        1
#> 3       40
#> 4       88
brfss2$menthlth <- ifelse(brfss2$menthlth == 88, 0, brfss2$menthlth)
brfss2
#>   menthlth
#> 1        0
#> 2        1
#> 3       40
#> 4        0
```

Or do it in your dplyr chain if you don't want to change the original values:

```
library(dplyr)
brfss2 <- data.frame(menthlth = c(0, 1, 40, 88))
brfss2 %>%
  mutate(menthlth = ifelse(menthlth == 88, 0, menthlth))
#>   menthlth
#> 1        0
#> 2        1
#> 3       40
#> 4        0
```